# How to pass image id to alarm service?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I use alarm service to start notifications. I want to have different image in notification based on which pendingIntent has called it. I tried passing this id via intent, but the app crashes

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
        //pass something to intent
        myIntent.putExtra("param", 999);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

And in service class, I catch it via

```
int test =  intent.getExtras().getInt("param", -1);
Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//the app crashes here!
```

However, the app crashes in the marked line.

How should I pass image id to the service so that I can use this ID to set image in the norifications?

**EDIT**

Here is the logcat when error happens

```
09-29 12:04:45.087: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService.MyAlarmService@2f9768a0 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService/.MyAlarmService (has extras) }: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3e7
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3e7
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:208)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
        at com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService.MyAlarmService.onStart(MyAlarmService.java:53)
        at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Does it crash on that line? Or does it simply not compile...? The latter makes more sense to me.

Comment: It compiles and generates run-time error. I am not saying this code it final, this is just a testing code as I am out of ideas how to pass image id to alarm service.

Comment: paste the logcat. also check what is the value of test.

Comment: The value of test is 999. The logcat says that the value does not exist but in debug mode I can see that test variable is initiated with the value. I will pass the logcat in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//the app crashes here!
```

Means you are sending an int as the message. This in turn means that you're telling Android to look for a String with resource id 999.
Change it to:

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(test), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//the app won't crash here
```

Comment: Funny! I though Toast automatically parses int to String :).